# What is $i^{\frac13}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

When asked the value of $i^{\frac13}$, should I present one solution, or the three solutions of $z^3=i$, $z\in\mathbb{C}$? If only one solution, what is the criteria? It seems principal roots can be ambiguous.

Comment: It would be determined by context. Absent any other context, if asked for a single value for $i^{1/3}$, the principal value would be the best choice. Though it would be worth noting the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would give the three roots. When a single one needs to be picked the standard one is given by taking the more general definition of $z^w = \exp(w \log z)$ and take [the principal value](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Principal_value) of $\log$.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, for $z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$, there are $n$ different $n$-th roots $z^{1/n}$.

When $z\in\mathbb R^+$, we sometimes pick the unique root that is real-valued and positive, and ignore the others (depends on the context). But in your context, you would list all three of them, they are all equally valid.

Comment: When $z\in \Bbb R^+$ the real valued root is not always unique.

Comment: For even $n$, you need to require positivity to be unique.

Comment: Thank you. And what about the case $i^i$, if I may ask?